# How to Implement Tab View in Apple Maps

Tags: uitableview, uitabbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to implement the Tab View like Apple has in their Apple Maps when you select a location and tap on the more details to reviews additional information about that location.

What would be the best way to implement this or how do you think Apple has implemented it. I know each tab view has a Table View inside each. Also for the Photos tab how do you think they implemented the content inside that tab. Was it using UICollectionView or a table view with a custom cell that has 4 photos in each cell row?

[image: Tab View in Apple Maps]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they're using one UITableView and on UISegmentedControl. With this combination every time the user selects and index on the segmented control, it changes a condition in the table's datasource and reloads the data. Here's an example of what something like that could look like to conditionally change the number of rows in the table

```
- (IBAction)segmentValueDidChange:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%d",sender.selectedSegmentIndex);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        return 5;
    }
    return 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but one more question. I am trying to put the segmented control in the header of the first section but I want it to scroll with the table view without making the tableview grouped. Is there a way to do this?